# I am trying to find a specific RPG that I can't remember the name of, player backstories affect setting

Tags: character-creation, product-identification

The game is a tabletop game, which was made by some of the same designers from Wizards of the Coast who left them, I believe it's loosely based on the same system as D&D. The idea of the game is that at the beginning the players all make up their own backstories, and they can be anything, and that helps determine the setting of the game (e.g. a dwarf characters makes a backstory where they are the child of the great Kingdom Ulfra of the North, well now there has to be a Kingdom Ulfra of the North in the setting).

I believe the game also had a free SRD type rulebook online and it's story-based. If anyone can point me towards this specific game, or one that sounds similar that would be much appreciated. As much as I love 5th Edition, I think my group could use something a bit more story-based and player-driven. I also know that I could just do this setting thing in any tabletop game but this one just seemed to stick out to me as being a bit simplified and elegant.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're thinking of [*13th Age*](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/17925/13th-age), by WotC alumni Jonathan Tweet and Rob Heinsoo, published in 2013. The way a character's background helps build the setting is through your One Unique Thing, and your Relationships to Icons. (Your actual *Background* is more about what sort of skills you're good at.)

> 13th Age is the new d20-rolling fantasy roleplaying game by Jonathan Tweet (3rd edition D&D, Over The Edge, Everway) and Rob Heinsoo (4th Edition D&D). It's a familiar fantasy game with spell books, Armor Class, dungeons, hit points, portals to other worlds and owlbears ripping people’s arms off. But it’s also a story-focused game where every character is unique, relationships are their most powerful resource and failure is more interesting than success.

13th Age has an SRD, and there are many sites online that reproduce it. I couldn't possibly recommend one in particular, but googling for "13th age srd" will give you a lot of choices.

And of course, the [print book from Pelgrane Press](http://site.pelgranepress.com/index.php/category/products/13th-age/) is well worth the price, as it includes material and guidance not in the SRD.

Comment: you are maximum bae

Comment: Without the "by the D&D guys" specification this'd actually be a lot of RPGs, like Fate where we can just list character aspects and now that implies things about the world.

Comment: @doppelgreener I was thinking the same thing reading it, then I hit “SRD” and all the previous puzzle pieces fell into place and the first five words of this answer popped into my head fully formed. (Until then I was vaguely wondering if it was *The Primal Order*.)

Comment: I was wondering if it was *Everway*, so I'm glad you got it before I guessed.

Comment: @BESW concerning that edit, `13th age srd` is computer-recognisable input in this scenario (it's in the context of giving that text to a search engine). I know of no screen reader that will impair readability of the text whilst it's marked up as code. Quotes work as well, it can be fine either way.